# SQLite: remove oldest rows with total size

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sort of storage in an SQLite DB. My columns are:

```
TABLE blobs
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  timestamp TIMESTAMP  -- Indexed
  data BLOB
  size INTEGER  -- Size of 'data' BLOB, bytes
```

I want to remove oldest rows such that their total size greater or equal `N` bytes. How can I do this? What SQL statement(s)? Please note I'm new to SQL in your answer.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for answers, but I don't need to find one oldest greater than `N`. I want to remove oldest rows `r1`, `r2`, and so on such that `sum(size(r1) + size(r2) + ...) > N`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will do:

```
DELETE FROM blobs
WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT ROWID FROM blobs
    WHERE (SELECT SUM(size) FROM blobs AS _ WHERE timestamp<=blobs.timestamp) <= N
);
```

Remember to replace `N` with actual number.

Use `SELECT *` instead of `DELETE` to check records to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you! This works just fine, but can you explain how `where timestamp <= blobs.timestamp` works? Why this makes to select in order and why `ORDER BY` doesn't work?

Comment: Within `(SELECT SUM(size) FROM blobs AS _ WHERE timestamp<=blobs.timestamp)`, unclassified `timestamp` will evaluate to inner `_.timestamp`. Classified `blobs.timestamp` will evaluate to outer `timestamp` (from `SELECT ROWID FROM blobs`). What do you mean with `ORDER BY` doesn't work? Results are independent from `ORDER BY`, but it works (where applicable).

Comment: Yes it works fine, I was confused with notation (as newbie). I have to get done something without enough time for warm up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
delete from blobs
where size >= N 
and timestamp = (select MIN(timestamp) from blobs);
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b9e21/2)

Comment: IMHO it's not correct, because it says: find oldest row and if its size is greater than `N` -> delete it, otherwise don't do anything.

Comment: Not oldest row, but rows, sum of those `>= N`.